# why I can't use findall()method in this code and what is the solution

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

In the code below it works correct until `findall`. How can I solve this? The main purpose of this code to receive the data stored in this site and this link contain xml data but I am trying to get the data asif from beautifulsoup and treat it as html file.
I know anther solution but I need to try this.

> traceback error    warnings.warn( Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\program\venv\try.py", line 10, in 
> datas=dp.findall('comment')   File
> "C:\Users\Abdullah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py",
> line 669, in findall return self._root.findall(path, namespaces)
>
> **TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable**

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request,urllib.error,urllib.parse
import re;import lxml
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
count =0
html=urllib.request.urlopen('http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_1591221.xml').read()
url=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
dp=ET.ElementTree(url)
datas=dp.findall('comment')
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Can't you do `url = BeautifulSoup(html, 'xml')` and then `url.find_all('comment')`? Also the method name is `find_all` not `findall`

Comment: @abdullahQureshee traceback error `AttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'find_all'. Did you mean: 'findall'?`
and  why  i can't do that?

Comment: No! I meant you don't need ElementTree. Bs can parse xml. Use bs.find_all()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_1591221.xml'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

comments = soup.select('comment')
print(comments)
```

Resulting in a list with all `comment` tags:

```
[<comment>
<name>Ajay</name>
<count>99</count>
</comment>, <comment>
<name>Sheonagh</name>
<count>99</count>
</comment>,...]
```